# Run multiple test suites with PHPUnit

Tags: unit-testing, phpunit

In my `phpunit.xml` I have a number of `<testsuite>`'s defined each of which defines a different aspect of my application to test. During development I don't want to necessarily run every test suite, only the ones in the aspect I'm working on.

However, when I want to test my full application I'd like to specify multiple test suites to run. Is there a way to do this from the command line?

Comment: If I understand it corrently, you currently run your tests with the addition of the `--testsuite <pattern>` filter to determine, which testsuite to run. If this is true, just leave this filter away to run the whole bunch of tests, or define `--group`s.

Comment: The documentation for `groups` is completely incomprehensible. There is simply no explanation of what groups are for or how to apply them. If you could add an answer with an example that would be much appreciated: http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.configuration.html#appendixes.configuration.groups

Comment: There are multiple ways to accomplish that. Please update your question with some example code of how you run it currently, then I'll have a look. By the way, the phpunit-documentation is quite extensive, but to tag tests with the `@group`-option and then run it with `phpunit --group MyGroup`-syntax, there is just not more to say (at least in my opinion).

Comment: Thanks Bjoern. That wasn't very helpful. Can you point me to the "quite extensive" documentation on how to use groups? Update my question with code? What code? An example is exactly what I'm looking for..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `@group` annotation to do this. Here are the docs for [annotations in phpUnit](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/appendixes.annotations.html).

You specify the group a test belongs to by putting `@group examplegroup` in the php docblock above each test class you'd like to be in the group.

For example:

```
<?php
/**
 * @group examplegroup
 *
 */
class StackTest extends PHPUnit_Framework_TestCase
{
    public function testPushAndPop()
    {
        $stack = array();
        $this->assertEquals(0, count($stack));

        array_push($stack, 'foo');
        $this->assertEquals('foo', $stack[count($stack)-1]);
        $this->assertEquals(1, count($stack));

        $this->assertEquals('foo', array_pop($stack));
        $this->assertEquals(0, count($stack));
    }
}
?>
```

Running the group from the command line works as follows:

`phpunit --group examplegroup`

Comment: That was better than what I was looking for! Thank you

Answer (score 4):

With the lastest versions of PHPUnit (since v6.1) you can simply separate suites with a comma (`--testsuite <name,...>`).

Examle: `phpunit --testdox --testsuite Users,Articles`

Documentation: https://phpunit.readthedocs.io/en/8.0/textui.html?highlight=--testsuite#command-line-options

Answer (score 3):

If each of your test suites has a different namespace, you could filter what test are run by using the `--filter` option.

For example: `phpunit --filter '/Controller|Tools/'`

All tests that have a namespace that matches the regex will be executed.

You have more examples in the [phpunit options documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/textui.html#textui.clioptions).